# Using the same RedirectToAction method in ActionMethods in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I basically want to check if the session is still valid for every GET and POST request in my application, however, I don't really want to keep copying and pasting the same code in to every Action Method, I was thinking of using a Base Controller so I can inherit the usage or a static helper controller class (if this can be done??). Are either of these ways the best (or even correct) approach to take?

Example of code

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult SimpleSearch()
    {
        // I want to run this code of every ActionResult for a GET AND POST
        if (!SessionStaticClass.IsUserLoggedIn())
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login, Login");
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: 5 - well the latest I believe

Comment: If you're using session to store login information, you are doing it very wrong, and making your site very insecure...

Comment: Don't worry I am not, no usernames or passwords in my session baby!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an action filter:

```
public class NotLoggedInFilter : FilterAttribute, IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         if (!SessionStaticClass.IsUserLoggedIn())
         {
             filterContext.Result = new RedirectToAction("Login, Login");
         }
    }
}
```

You can then decorate controllers or actions with the attribute, or even have it run for all actions by adding it to the global filter collection.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) 
{    
    filters.Add(new NotLoggedInFilter());
}
```

However, you might want to have a look at authentication filters as a way of handling user authentication instead of using the `SessionStaticClass` class. A good overview of filter types in MVC can be found [here](http://hackwebwith.net/asp-net-mvc-5-action-filter-types-overview/).